# Show two values bindings in a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display the id and descritption of a document on a dropdown menu list but I don't know how to do it. So far it works fine but shows only reference document.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="TrainingDocIDTextBox" runat="server"
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="ReferenceDocument"
DataValueField="TrainingDocID"
onselectedindexchanged="TrainingDocIDTextBox_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem? Code looks fine with DataTextField and DataValueField.

Comment: @monty, it is possible to have a dropdownlist with two values?

Comment: Out of the box no, but you could use the workaround by concatenating values like Vimvq1987 suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. But you can work around this by combining ReferenceDocument & TrainingDocID in the query, for example:

```
Select [TrainingDocID], [TrainingDocID] + ',' + [ReferenceDocument] as [RefrenceDoc] from ...
```

Comment: Is there any possible? like combination of dropdownlist and repeater?

Comment: It's possible, but it will take you more time in coding and take your app more time to run :)